# Avro not populating square brackets for Array type

Tags: scala, avro, avro4s

I have the following Avro schema:

```
{
"name": "schema_name",
"type": "record",
"fields" : [
{
"name": "schema",
"type": "string"
},
{
  "name": "data",
  "type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items":
      {
        "name": "data",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
  }
},
{
  "name":"flag",
  "type":"string"
}
]
}
```

And I am using it to generate Avro messages from a text file:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val avroSchemaStr = Source.fromFile("avro_schema.txt").mkString
  val avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchemaStr)

  Source.fromFile("phone_numbers.txt").getLines.foreach { msg =>
    println(fixedWidthToAvro(msg, avroSchema))
  }
}

def fixedWidthToAvro(record: String, avroSchema: Schema): GenericRecord = {
  val childSchema = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema).getSchema.getField("data").schema.getElementType
  val parentRrecord = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema)
  val childRecord = new GenericData.Record(childSchema)

  childRecord.put("phone_number", "1234567890")
  parentRrecord.put("schema", "schema_name")
  parentRrecord.put("data", childRecord)
  parentRrecord.put("flag", "I")

  println(parentRrecord)
  parentRrecord
}
```

Everything works well, and I get the below output for a given message:

```
{"schema": "schema_name", "data": {"phone_number": "1234567890"}, "flag": "I"}
```

However, as I declared `data` field type as `array` I was expecting it to be wrapped in square brackets like a collection. Something like:

```
{"schema": "schema_name", "data": [{"phone_number": "1234567890"}], "flag": "I"}
```

I want the `data` filed to be wrapped in square brackets. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements in the record with the name `data`. One is the array, and the other one is the element name inside that array, and I think that's what is confusing you.

When you pass `schema.getElementType` to `Record`, you're generating a single record and neglecting to create an `Array[Record]` to hold all these records.

What you need is an array which will capacitate all your records:

```
val avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schema)
val childSchema = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema).getSchema.getField("data").schema

val parentRecord = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema)
val childRecords = new GenericData.Array[GenericData.Record](1024, childSchema)

val childRecord = new GenericData.Record(childSchema.getElementType)

childRecord.put("phone_number", "33333")
childRecords.add(childRecord)

parentRecord.put("schema", "schema_name")
parentRecord.put("data", childRecords)
parentRecord.put("flag", "I")

println(parentRecord)
```

Yields:

```
{"schema": "schema_name", "data": [{"phone_number": "33333"}], "flag": "I"}
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked, thanks for the detail description and solution.